# What does "var app = app || {};" do?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Im looking at some Backbone.js examples and they have `var app = app || {};` at the top of all .js files. I understand the literal meaning of this, but what does it do in reference to everything else?

Edit: you guys are really really fast.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It will define the variable `app` to an empty object if it is not already defined.

This works because being undefined evaluates to `false` in Javascript.

If it is defined, it may still be re-defined as an empty object if it has a value which evalutes to `false`, such as an empty string.

Comment: Specifically... defines `app` to the empty object if the value of `app` is falsy.

Comment: inception ! upvoted +1

Comment: *"If it is already defined, it will re-define it within the scope of the file."* What does re-define it within the scope of the file mean? The variable is already in scope.

Comment: Yes, it will effectively do nothing since it is already in global scope. If this was in a function it would re-define it in local scope. I will clarify.

Comment: @nullability: That's what I mean. If it's already defined in a function scope, it won't be redefined unless the defined value happened to be a falsey value. Though if we're in a function scope, and it has already been defined, there's no point in using `var` again.

Comment: OK, then `var app = app;` would effectively do nothing.

Comment: This answer is slightly incorrect.  This answer should say "if it is truthy" instead of "if it is not already defined."  The following example shows why this answer is incorrect: `var app = false; app = app || {}; /*App now equals {} because app was "falsey" */`.  See @recursive's answer for the correct answer.

Answer (score 17):

The `||` operator in javascript will return the first operand if it is "truthy".  If not, it will return the second operand.  If `app` has not been assigned, it will be `undefined`, which is "falsey".  Thus if it is not defined or is otherwise falsey, an empty object `{}` will be assigned to `app`.

Answer (score 6):

This means **"define app as an empty object if it's not already defined"**.

The `OR` operator in `JavaScript` does not necessarily yield a `boolean`. If the left-hand side of the expression yields `false` then the assignment takes the right-hand side of the expression.

Answer (score 2):

If `app` is already defined, the it does nothing.
If `app` is not defined, then it's equivalent to `var app = {};`